# Bindings & mutations in nested object hierarchies

Tags: svelte, store

I am currently struggling to implement a "simple" example illustrating a binding to a nested object that gets mutated "somewhere" in the application and has the mutation reflected in all components which reference the component.

I created https://svelte.dev/repl/eeb39d0d274147e8bd3d273587ce56b6?version=3.55.1 which works "almost" as I hoped it would out of the box, but I guess it can't. I assume that in In my example, the  `Display.svelte` component gets updated outside of the loop because of the bind to a field / variable. I guess it does not work in the loop as the compiler does not maintain a context, and selection is not available in the loop's scope.

I wonder if there are established patterns to propagate changes through decomposed user interfaces.  Would one way be to have a store for each field, which could be mutated?

```js
type Item = {
  value: writable<number>
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting to see the changes made to the selection reflected under 'All items'? https://svelte.dev/repl/c59835fbdd974d13911a051379a02f69?version=3.55.1

Comment: No, I hoped the binding expression created by the compiler would create more "magic." But at this point I don't understand how changes can be consistently propagated. I understand why it works for `selection`: everything is known in the scope. But how can I notify a view about it's model's updates in the given example? In the example, selection can be used in the loop but the binding expression (I added an if / else condition). But how would I do it, if the view and the model is decomposed in smaller components?

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that you actually changed my example and made it work. My question targets cases, in which the changes need to be propagated from different part of the application and a simple reassignment is not possible.

Comment: Here's your example without store, component and #each loop https://svelte.dev/repl/4ec946da15274bcb8ba5bc3a203a5e04?version=3.55.1 I think what's relevant is the behaviour of the group binding that only seems to register assignments to the associated variable but never updates the UI

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have the mutations of the object occur within custom methods of the store.

So wherever you define the store in your application, export custom methods that mutate the store as you wish, and call THESE methods to perform the mutation.

```js
//- store declaration
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

function createStore() {
    const { subscribe, set, update } = writable([]);

    return {
        subscribe,
        append: (item) => update((array) => [...array, item]),
        reset: () => set([])
    }
}

export const store = createStore()
```

Then in your various app components - or any other Javascript function/method anywhere else in your app - you can simply call the custom `store.append()` method on your store and svelte components WILL detect the updates.

[Example REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/cf140fd8371f44cd8d79936e2dc79237?version=3.55.1)

Comment: Why is the additional level of indirection relevant when it’s mostly about the store interface used to bind to the custom store? How does that relate to mutations of inner objects when UI elements are not bound explicitly to the store, but only objects contained by the store?

Comment: If I understand the question: when objects are referenced in your svelte component, svelte's internals detect their usage in your component and will update the UI when child properties are modified. However, when values are updated outside of the component, in other parts of the application, the svelte components are not wired up to update the UI when the values change. But, if you use the store's `set` and `update` methods you can trigger those updates where simply modifying those properties would not work.